# I'm getting twice request with my query

Tags: php, request

Whenever I try it on the database, it subtracts only 1 to the book_total, but whenever I try it in my page, it lessens the book_total by 2. I tried searching for answers, but there are so many answers which did not help.

```
<div class="fInput"><input type="number" name="bookCount" value="1" min="1" 
max="<?php echo($row[0][2]); ?>"></div>
<div class="fInput"><input type="date" min="<?php echo($today); ?>" 
name="dateBorrowed" value="<?php echo($today); ?>" id="date"></div>

$query = "UPDATE books SET book_total=book_total-1 WHERE 
book_id=".$row[0][0];
$stmt = $conn->query($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

EDIT:

Even this code when refreshed or entered subtracts 2 from book_total where it should just be subtracted by 1.

```
<?php
require "../db/db.php";

$query = "UPDATE books SET book_total=book_total-1 WHERE book_id=1859475";
$stmt = $conn->query($query);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: In the edit, it is suppose to be subtract 1 from book_total yet it keeps subtracting 2. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: If your application is isolated from rest of the world, then you run the query two times. Either it's done in one cycle (i.e. query is executed in two different places), or asynchronously, i.e. via ajax requests or first time when form is shown, second time when it's submitted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity you give. I'm using XAMPP, but I will restart the computer, I am using an AJAX on one of my page, but the edited part doesn't have/require an AJAX, I make a fresh page where I can test the said query but unfortunately, same result. Anyways, is there a way for me to check the execution of codes? I am a beginner at web dev so I really don't have much the idea of what to do. Thank you!